# Client doesn't detect Server disconnection

Tags: c++, grpc

In my application (c++) I have a service exposed as:

grpc foo(stream Request) returns (Reply) { }

The issue is that when the server goes down (CTRL-C) the stream on the client side keeps going indeed the

grpc::ClientWriter::Write

doesn't return false. I can confirm that using netstat I don't see any connection between the client and the server (apart a TIME_WAIT one that after a while goes away) and the client keeps calling that Write without errors.

Is there a way to see if the underlying connection is still up instead to rely on the Write return value ? I use grpc version 1.12

**update**

I discovered that the underlying channel goes in status IDLE but still the ClientWriter::Write doesn't report the error, I don't know if this is intended. During the streaming I'm trying now to reestablish a connection with the server every time the channel status is not GRPC_CHANNEL_READY

Comment: You could overlay the protocol with some kind of are-you-there message that you send on regular intervals?

Comment: I can but that is an "hack"

Comment: I discovered that the underlying channel goes in status IDLE but still the ClientWriter::Write doesn't report the error, I don't know if this is intended. During the streaming I'm trying now to reestablish a connection with the server.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen in a few scenarios but the most common element is a connection issue. We have KEEPALIVE support in gRPC to tackle exactly this issue. For C++, please refer to https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/keepalive.md on how to set this up. Essentially, endpoints would send pings at certain intervals and expect a reply within a certain timeframe.

Comment: Keepalive won't prevent `grpc::ClientWriter::Write` to return true as long as the underlying connection is supposed to be ok. So the code may think that messages are correctly sent but there are not, and they will be just simply lost when `grpc::ClientWriter::Write` finally returns false.